# AppArmor issues with Libvirt

Tags: libvirt, apparmor, cockpit

I have a fresh Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 and Debian 12.1.0 installed and updated. Along with Cockpit and Cockpit virtual machines on both tests machines.

I am getting the following errors and warning when looking at the log section in Cockpit:

```
Failed to read AppArmor profiles list '/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles': Permission denied libvirtd

Failed to open file '/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles': Permission denied libvirtd

Failed to read AppArmor profiles list '/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles': Permission denied libvirtd

Failed to open file '/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles': Permission denied libvirtd
```

The virtual machines start up and has no issues. However, the errors pop up after every reboot once I click the virtual machines section on Cockpit. These errors only show then, and not when I do NOT go to virtual machines section in Cockpit. So it seems to only start once you go to that section in Cockpit.

The `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.libvirtd` does have the line:

```
/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles r,
```

My user has also been added to groups `libvirt`, `kvm` and `sudo`.

Also, when running the following command without `sudo` and not as root on the terminal, then I also get a permission denied. I checked the folder permissions and it does have read permissions and belong to the group root:

```shell
cat /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles
```

Has anyone else experience this issue? Any solution to get it fixed with or without disabling AppArmor for KVM? or can the errors be safely ignored?